# Parsing a file in python and removing unwanted lines

Tags: python

I'm looking to parse a file and remove all lines which does not have the word 'Asia' in it. Also i want to ignore the headers

```
Header record
India is in Asia
Japan is in Asia
Germany is in Europe
China is in Asia
US is in NortAmerica
Brazil is in SouthAmerica
Trailer record
```

Is there a way by which i can improve the below code

```
fhand = open('P:\Python\Python.txt')
a=[]
for line in fhand:
    a.append(line.split())
for i in a[1:-1]:
    if 'Asia' not in i:
        a.remove(i)
print (a[1:-1])
```

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the headers are anything that do not have the VALID_MARKER below. Hence, you can iterate as such and filter this way:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

IGNORE_COUNTRY = 'Asia'
VALID_MARKER = 'is in'

cleaned_lines = []
for line in data:
    if IGNORE_COUNTRY in line or VALID_MARKER not in line:
        continue
    cleaned_lines.append(line.rstrip())

print cleaned_lines
```

output:

```
['Germany is in Europe', 'US is in NortAmerica', 'Brazil is in SouthAmerica']
```

Comment: Additionally, if `Header` is always the first line only, then `f.readlines()[1:]` or similar could work.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot to both of you

Comment: Please accept if the solution works for ya, otherwise let us know if you need clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file, get the contents with `readlines()`, and then choose only the lines you want: containing "is in", but not "Asia":

```
clean = [line.strip() for line in open('P:\Python\Python.txt').readlines() 
             if "is in" in line and 
                "Asia" not in line]
print(clean)
```

Output:

```
[Germany is in Europe', 'US is in NortAmerica', 'Brazil is in SouthAmerica']
```

Note that, if you're writing to another file, the list comprehension can be put directly into the `write` command, and the process collapses to one long line.

Also, this might be much easier from the command line.  In UNIX (Linux), `awk` and other  are very good at this.

Comment: Great! I'm still a beginner with python and was trying to put the code in a way which makes it easier for me. for line in open('P:\Python\Python.txt').readlines():
    if "is in" in line and "Asia" not in line: so does this code return the line?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine, but i'm just trying to understand how does the presence of line.strip() before the for statement is working?

Comment: If you unravel the logic, `strip()` is the *last* operation applied: it takes the whitespace off the ends of the line -- most notably the newline character at the end.

Comment: Got it :). Just now i understood that you have used list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to ignore header? No problem with trailer? If so:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

with open('data.txt') as file:
    file.readline() # ignore header
    for line in filterfalse(lambda line: 'Asia' in line, file):
        print(line)
```